# How is using Synchronizer Token Pattern to prevent CSRF safe?

Tags: javascript, security, web, csrf

I have been reading about using a synchronizer token pattern to prevent CSRF (CSRF meaning Cross-site request forgery.), and I don't understand how it actually safe.

Let's say I have a fake bank site fakebank.com with two urls:

- `fakebank.com/withdrawForm.html` - a GET request which displays the withdraw money form
- `fakebank.com/doWithdraw` - POST to this url to do the withdraw

My understanding of the security flaw is that `maliciousSite.com` can spoof a POST request to `fakebank.com/doWithdraw`, and if you're currently logged in to fakebank, the POST will be successful.

Let's say we implement a Synchronizer Token Pattern which will embed a secret code on `fakebank.com/withdrawForm.html`. Can't `maliciousSite.com` just spoof a GET request for that form, parse the html result, get the token, and then create the POST request with that token?

This is assuming fakebank.com isn't checking HTTP Referrer or Origin or `maliciousSite.com` is successfully spoofing that the Referrer/Origin is fakebank.com.

Comment: https://github.com/JudeNiroshan/CSRF_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The reason why this is secure, and `maliciousSite.com` cannot simply do a `GET`, steal the token, and then do a `POST` is that the request is done by the user's browser, not by the server at `maliciousSite.com`.  All data returned from `fakebank.com` is returned *to the user's browser*, not to the server at `maliciousSite.com`.  If `maliciousSite.com` does perform a GET to retrieve a token, it will be a different token than was issued to the user.  `maliciousSite.com` cannot set this cookie into the user's browser to be submitted to `fakebank.com` because of same-domain restrictions.

The CSRF `POST` attack works by tricking the user's browser into requesting `fakebank.com/withdrawForm.html` directly using a properly formed `POST` request.  The server at `fakebank.com` happily executes the requested `POST`, thus transferring funds using the parameters supplied in the `POST` body (which include a destination account belonging to the attacker that was put there by `maliciousSite.com`).  The server at `maliciousSite.com` doesn't need to see the data returned, because the action has been taken (unless `fakebank.com` uses these CSRF tokens, which the `maliciousSite.com` can't possibly know unless it has been divulged in some way.  It can't ask for it).  If `fakebank.com` is using CSRF tokens, then `maliciousSite.com` will submit a `POST` request that is missing the token, thus indicating a potential CSRF attack in progress.

Vulnerabilities of this method include using a CSRF token that is not kept sufficiently secret and is divulged in some way.  Also, if the CSRF token is not sufficiently random, then `maliciousSite.com` might be able to guess it.  Also, if there is a weakness in the browser's enforcement of same domain policy, this could be exploited.  Generally speaking, modern browsers are not vulnerable to this.

Please let me know if this is an insufficient explanation and I'll attempt to articulate it a little better for you.

Comment: If you're able to inject javascript into a user's browser in order to initiate the attack, what's to stop you simply embedding some jquery to do a GET request, parse it, then do a POST all within the same `<script>` tag?

Comment: @SLC If you can inject script code into the user's browser, then you're no longer talking about CSRF but rather XSS.  At that point, the CSRF token is not only worthless, but the least of your problems.

Comment: Specifically, the reason you can't just do a jquery GET request. Is that credentialed XHR (js initiated) requests is that this request will be blocked by the victims browser unless explicit CORS headers are set to allow the request from maliciousite.com AND allow credentials. Even wildcard will be blocked. E.g. make sure your site never returns: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: malicioussite.com (many online CORS tutorials has the very bad practice yo set allow to the incoming Origin header) AND Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true.

Answer (score 2):

And that is exactly the point. The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in the browser does not allow *GET* requests to other sites. So no site can GET the CSRF token from another just using Javascipt within the browser.