# Securing REST Service using a simple Token

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-authentication, wcf-web-api

I have a drop-down in my application for which i populate the data using an Ajax call as shown below. This works fine and my Web API URL is "http://example.com/Service.svc/json/getairports"

```
    $(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://example.com/Service.svc/json/getairports", {}, function (data) {
        $("#airport-departure-modal, #destination-airport-modal").html("")
        $.each(data, function (index, element) {
            $("#airport-departure-modal, #destination-airport-modal").append("<option id=" + element["AirportCode"] + ">" + element["AirportName"] + "</option>");
        });
    });
});
```

But my worry is security since anyone can view this URL using view source or developer tools. So i wanted to bring in a token and pass it to the service like "http://example.com/Service.svc/json/getairports?token=SECUREKEY" but i wonder how this can solve the problem since secure key also visible in the view source. **So my question is how can i keep the secure key invisible in the client side or dynamically passed only when the ajax call is initiated?**

Just for information, i will be using HTTPS in production so that sniffing over the wire is taken care. Also not that, this service is going to be used only within the same application though Web API service might be hosted on a separate node.

Kindly advise if there might be some alternative but simple solution for the above scenario. i am aware of other advanced mechanisms such as OAuth,HMAC, Amazon S3, etc. But i just want to have a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to solve? Do you want to prevent a user from calling your API programmatically? If your browser can get something, so can a user with the power of view-source - so that's a fruitless effort. Really though, it sounds like you want to prevent CSRF.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049721/how-is-using-synchronizer-token-pattern-to-prevent-csrf-safe) should be helpful.